# Call to notifyItemChanged not updating my recyclerView

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I have a recyclerview that is populating data from a database. After handling a click event that increases the number of times a particular row has been click, calls to both notifyItemChanged(position) and notifyDatasetChanged has no effect on the view. Please what am I doing wrong

Here is my code

Adapter

```
public class ExaminationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ExaminationAdapter.EAViewHolder> {
private Cursor mCursor;
private static ExaminationClickListener clickListener;




public interface ExaminationClickListener {

    void onClick(View v, int rowID, int position, boolean longClick);
}

public ExaminationAdapter (ExaminationClickListener clickListener){
    this.clickListener = clickListener;
}

@Override
public EAViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    // inflate the android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1 layout
    View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(
            R.layout.recyclerview_examination, parent, false);
    return new EAViewHolder(view); // return current item's ViewHolder
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(EAViewHolder holder, int position) {
    mCursor.moveToPosition(position);
    holder.setRowID(mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndex(SinEntry._ID)));
    holder.mTextView1.setText(mCursor.getString(mCursor.getColumnIndex(SinEntry.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION)));
    int count = mCursor.getInt(mCursor.getColumnIndex(ConfessionContract.PersonToSinEntry.COLUMN_COUNT));
    holder.mTextView2.setText(String.valueOf(count));
    holder.setPosition(position);

    /*try {
    }
    catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
    holder.mTextView2.setText("0");
    }*/
}




@Override
public int getItemCount() { return (mCursor != null) ? mCursor.getCount() : 0;    }

// swap this adapter's current Cursor for a new one
public void swapCursor(Cursor cursor) {
    mCursor = cursor;
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}

public class EAViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  {
    public final TextView mTextView1;
    public final TextView mTextView2;
    private long rowID;
    private int position;

    public EAViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        mTextView1 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtSin);
        mTextView2 = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.txtSinCount);

        itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                clickListener.onClick(v, (int) rowID, position, false);
            }
        });
        itemView.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                clickListener.onClick(v, (int) rowID, position, true);
                return true;
            }
        });
    }

    // set the database row ID for the examination in this ViewHolder
    public void setRowID(long rowID) {
        this.rowID = rowID;
    }

    public void setPosition (int position ) {
    this.position = position;
    }
}
}
```

Fragment

```
    public class ExaminationFragment extends Fragment implements LoaderManager.LoaderCallbacks<Cursor> {
    // TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose names that match
    // the fragment initialization parameters, e.g. ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
    private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
    private static final int EXAMINATION_LOADER = 2;// identifies Loader
    public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private String selection;
    private String[] selectionArgs;
    private int id;


    // TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
    private int commandmentID;
    private String mParam2;

    private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;
    private ExaminationAdapter examinationAdapter;
    private static final String[] EXAMINATION_COLUMNS = {

            ConfessionContract.SinEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + ConfessionContract.SinEntry._ID,
            ConfessionContract.SinEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + ConfessionContract.SinEntry.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION,
            ConfessionContract.PersonToSinEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + ConfessionContract.PersonToSinEntry.COLUMN_PERSON_ID,
            ConfessionContract.PersonToSinEntry.TABLE_NAME + "." + ConfessionContract.PersonToSinEntry.COLUMN_COUNT

    };
    private static final String[] COUNT_COLUMNS ={
            ConfessionContract.PersonToSinEntry.COLUMN_COUNT
    };
    public ExaminationFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

   public static ExaminationFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
        ExaminationFragment fragment = new ExaminationFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        SharedPreferences user = getContext().getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, 0);
        int vocation = user.getInt("vocation", 99);
        long dob = user.getLong("birthDate", 99);
        int sex = user.getInt("sex", 99);
        id = user.getInt("id", 99);

        if (getArguments() != null) {
            commandmentID = getArguments().getInt(ExaminationActivity.COMMANDMENT_URI);
        }
        selection = "(" +ConfessionContract.SinEntry.COLUMN_COMMANDMENT_ID + " = ? AND " +
                Utility.calculateAgeBracket(dob) + " AND " +
                Utility.vocationSelection(vocation)+ " AND " +
                Utility.sexSelection(sex) + " AND " +
                ConfessionContract.PersonToSinEntry.COLUMN_PERSON_ID + " = ?" + ")"
        + " OR " +"(" +ConfessionContract.SinEntry.COLUMN_COMMANDMENT_ID + " = ? AND " +
                Utility.calculateAgeBracket(dob) + " AND " +
                Utility.vocationSelection(vocation)+ " AND " +
                Utility.sexSelection(sex) + " AND " +
                ConfessionContract.PersonToSinEntry.COLUMN_PERSON_ID + " is NULL" + ")";

        selectionArgs = new String[]{String.valueOf(commandmentID), String.valueOf(id), String.valueOf(commandmentID) };
        getLoaderManager().initLoader(EXAMINATION_LOADER, null, this);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_examination, container, false);

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewE);

        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        examinationAdapter = new ExaminationAdapter(new ExaminationAdapter.ExaminationClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v, int rowID, int position, boolean longClick) {
                if (longClick) {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), rowID + " long click", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else {
                    updateCount(rowID, position);
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), String.valueOf(rowID), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }
        });

        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(examinationAdapter); // set the adapter
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
        return rootView;

    }

    private void updateCount(int rowID, int position) {
        int count = 0;
        String selection = ConfessionContract.PersonToSinEntry.COLUMN_PERSON_ID + " = ?"
                + " AND " + ConfessionContract.PersonToSinEntry.COLUMN_SINS_ID + " = ?";
        String[] selectionArgs ={String.valueOf(id), String.valueOf(rowID)};
        Cursor cursor = getActivity().getContentResolver().query(ConfessionContract.PersonToSinEntry.CONTENT_URI,
                COUNT_COLUMNS,
                selection,
                selectionArgs,
                null);
        if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()){
            count = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(ConfessionContract.PersonToSinEntry.COLUMN_COUNT));
        }

        if (cursor != null) {
            cursor.close();
        }

        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(ConfessionContract.PersonToSinEntry.COLUMN_PERSON_ID, id);
        contentValues.put(ConfessionContract.PersonToSinEntry.COLUMN_SINS_ID, rowID);
        contentValues.put(ConfessionContract.PersonToSinEntry.COLUMN_COUNT, count + 1);


        int sinUri = getActivity().getContentResolver().update(
                ConfessionContract.PersonToSinEntry.buildSinUri(rowID),
                contentValues,
                selection,
                selectionArgs);

        **mRecyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemChanged(position);**

    }


    // TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
    public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
        if (mListener != null) {
            mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
        }
    }



    @Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
            mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
        } else {
            throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                    + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onDetach() {
        super.onDetach();
        mListener = null;
    }


    @Override
    public Loader<Cursor> onCreateLoader(int id, Bundle args) {
        CursorLoader cursorLoader;
        String sortOrder = ConfessionContract.SinEntry._ID + " COLLATE NOCASE ASC";

        cursorLoader = new CursorLoader(getActivity(),
                ConfessionContract.SinEntry.CONTENT_URI, // Uri of sins table
                EXAMINATION_COLUMNS, // null projection returns all columns
                selection, // null selection returns all rows
                selectionArgs, // no selection arguments
                sortOrder); // sort order

        return cursorLoader;
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoadFinished(Loader<Cursor> loader, Cursor data) {

        examinationAdapter.swapCursor(data);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLoaderReset(Loader<Cursor> loader) {
        examinationAdapter.swapCursor(null);
    }

    public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
        // TODO: Update argument type and name
        void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
    }


    }
```

Comment: Did you ever find out what was causing the issue? I have the exact same problem.

Comment: @SudoPlz did you resolve this issue?

Comment: @HB. I was trying that on a react-native project, and it was all layout weirdness that prevented the layout pass to take place.

It won't really answer the question if I posted code here.

Comment: @SudoPlz Okay thanks for the reply